# Is it possible to use OpenPrinter, WritePrinter and other functions of winspool.drv in VB5 on a printer through a Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: windows, printing, rdp

I am working on a legacy project in VB5 that prints on thermal printers using winspool.drv  functions. They are as follows (module lineprint.bas):

```
Option Explicit
Private Type DOCINFO
   pDocName As String
   pOutputFile As String
   pDatatype As String
End Type
Private Declare Function ClosePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal _
  hPrinter As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EndDocPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal _
  hPrinter As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EndPagePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal _
  hPrinter As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias _
  "OpenPrinterA" (ByVal pPrinterName As String, phPrinter As Long, _
   ByVal pDefault As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function StartDocPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias _
  "StartDocPrinterA" (ByVal hPrinter As Long, ByVal Level As Long, _
  pDocInfo As DOCINFO) As Long
Private Declare Function StartPagePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal _
  hPrinter As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WritePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal _
  hPrinter As Long, pBuf As Any, ByVal cdBuf As Long, _
  pcWritten As Long) As Long
Dim lhPrinter As Long
Dim lDoc As Long
Dim MyDocInfo As DOCINFO
Dim lReturn As Long
Dim lpcWritten As Long
Dim PrinterOK As Boolean
Dim mImpressora As String
Public Sub OpenLinePrinter(DeviceName As String)
   mImpressora = UCase$(DeviceName)
   lReturn = OpenPrinter(DeviceName, lhPrinter, 0)
   PrinterOK = lReturn <> 0
   MyDocInfo.pDocName = App.ProductName
   MyDocInfo.pOutputFile = vbNullString
   MyDocInfo.pDatatype = vbNullString
   lDoc = StartDocPrinter(lhPrinter, 1, MyDocInfo)
   Call StartPagePrinter(lhPrinter)
End Sub

Public Sub LineFeedLinePrinter()
Dim sWrittenData As String
   If PrinterOK Then
       sWrittenData = vbCrLf
       lReturn = WritePrinter(lhPrinter, ByVal sWrittenData, _
           Len(sWrittenData), lpcWritten)
   End If
End Sub

Public Sub PrintLinePrinter(Linha As String, Optional NewLine As Boolean = False)
Dim sWrittenData As String
   If PrinterOK Then
       sWrittenData = Linha
       If NewLine Then sWrittenData = sWrittenData & vbCrLf
           lReturn = WritePrinter(lhPrinter, ByVal sWrittenData, _
              Len(sWrittenData), lpcWritten)
   End If
End Sub

Public Sub EjectLinePrinter()
Dim sWrittenData As String
   If PrinterOK Then
       sWrittenData = Chr$(12)
       lReturn = WritePrinter(lhPrinter, ByVal sWrittenData, _
          Len(sWrittenData), lpcWritten)
   End If
End Sub

Public Sub CloseLinePrinter(Optional ByVal CutPaper = True)
Dim I As Integer, S$
   If PrinterOK Then
       If CutPaper Then AcionarGuilhotina
       PrinterOK = False
       lReturn = EndPagePrinter(lhPrinter)
       lReturn = EndDocPrinter(lhPrinter)
       lReturn = ClosePrinter(lhPrinter)
   End If
End Sub
```

A very simple example of the use of the functions

```
OpenLinePrinter("EPSON TM-T20")
PrintLinePrinter("TEST LINE",true)
CloseLinePrinter()
```

This works perfectly if the application is running locally and the printer is local or shared. But when the application is run in a RDP connection and tries to print on a local printer through the connection, nothing prints. To explain it better: printer is connected to an RDP client, shows on the list of printers in the serever, prints normally a test page from the server (connection), and , for instance, through Notepad, but not through the application.

So my questions are: 1) is it possible? 2) if it is, am I missing something, both in the code or in some configuration on the cleint or server?

Unfortunately, being this a legacy changing the development language is out of question.

Thanks for your help.